# How to get last lines from table, but need all information of line?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select, greatest-n-per-group

there is oracle table like this ( this table is result of complex join query)

```
objectId                              xml     DATETIME                    sourceId
7d2a2d8e-ec89-4579-a77e-e3e07414029c  ...     2019-11-28 10:40:34.659     1-FR
6c4476ab-637f-43e8-b162-e215c6d99758  ...     2019-11-28 10:40:34.718     1-I1
4b626ed7-fd66-46e3-98b4-e235c029f92f  ...     2019-11-28 10:40:51.477     1-FR
8d4633c7-5422-46c9-a653-632bed534b60  ...     2019-11-28 10:40:51.505     1-I1
```

Table name is PORT

So, how to create query for get only last by DATATIMECALC lines?

Expected result is

```
objectId                              xml     DATETIME                    sourceId
4b626ed7-fd66-46e3-98b4-e235c029f92f  ...     2019-11-28 10:40:51.477     1-FR
8d4633c7-5422-46c9-a653-632bed534b60  ...     2019-11-28 10:40:51.505     1-I1
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use row_number()

```
select a.* from 
(
select *, row_number() over(PARTITION by sourceId order by datetime desc) rn
from t
) a where a.rn=1
```

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you want the last line per `sourceId`, with records ordered by `datetime`. A method that I would expect to be quite efficient in Oracle is to filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select p.*
from port p
where p.datetime = (
    select max(p1.datetime)
    from port p1
    where p1.sourceId = p.sourceId
)
```

For performance, you want an index on `(sourceId, datetime)`.

Answer (score 0):

please use below query..

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY sourceId ORDER BY DATETIME DESC
            ) row_num
    FROM y
    ) x
WHERE x.row_num = 1
```